# simple question related to the arithmetic of binomial coefficient

Tags: arithmetic, binomial-coefficients

Bonjour,

The problem i have follows from the definition of the binomial coefficient:

$\frac{n(n-1)...(n-k+1)}{k!} = {n \choose k}$

For 0$\leq{i}$ and i less than k, we observe that:

$\frac{n-i}{k-i}\geq\frac{n}{k}$

Is there a simple and intuitive arithmetic proof of this inequality ?

This inequality is sometimes used to prove that:

$(\frac{n}{k})^k\leq {n \choose k}$

Comment: You also need $k\leq n$.

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward. Note that $\frac{n-i}{k-i}\geq \frac{n}{k}$ iff $nk-ik\geq nk-ni$, which is true iff $-ik\geq -in$ which again is true (for our $i$) iff $k\leq n$, and this gives the answer.

Comment: user45150: thank you very much !

Answer (score 1):

If $0 < i < k < n$, then 
$$\frac{n-i}{k-i} = \frac{n}{k}\times\frac{1 - \frac{i}{n}}{1-\frac{i}{k}} > \frac{n}{k}$$
since $1-\frac{i}{n} < 1 - \frac{i}{k}$. For an *intuitive* explanation let us look at
a set of $n$ balls of which $k$ balls are blue and $n-k$ are not blue.  Then, the *proportion* of blue balls in 
the set
is $\frac{k}{n}$. Throw away $i$ blue balls. Then, the *proportion* of blue balls in the 
reduced set is smaller because you have thrown away *proportionately*
far more blue balls than non-blue balls.  That is,
$$\frac{k-i}{n-i} < \frac{k}{n} \Rightarrow \frac{n}{k} < \frac{n-i}{k-i}.$$

Comment: thank you. To resort to set-theory is always useful.

Comment: I'll take a close look to this !